# Need regular expression to replace all things inside string

Tags: sql, regex

I am using below which is working fine but I need to add an expression which will replace anything (like special characters, numbers, etc all things should cover currently I have used [A-Z])

```
select regexp_replace('002 - KLAMPFER - Sy 52-5-5+L', '- [A-Z]+ -', '- XXXXXXX -')
  from dual;
```

output:

```
002 - XXXXXXX - Sy 52-5-5+L
```

but in input string we might get special chars,number,spaces,german special chars instead of "KLAMPFER" sting so I need regex which will cover these all.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: 'Anything' including Space and `-`? Isn't it obvious that this could be problematic?

Comment: @anubhava  Its not working for spaces

Comment: Then try this: `regex: ' - .+? - '`

Answer (score 1):

With any regex engine that supports non-fixed with lookbehinds, you can use

```js
(?<=^\S+\s+-\s(?:(?!\s+-\s).)*)\S
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YX9ibT/2). *Details*:

- `(?<=^\S+\s+-\s(?:(?! - ).)*)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with

  - `^` - start of string
  - `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars
  - `\s+-\s` - one or more whitespaces, `-` and a whitespace
  - `(?:(?!\s+-\s).)*`  - any char other than a line break char, as many occurrences as possible, not starting the "one or more whitespaces, `-` and a whitespace" sequence
- `\S` - any non-whitespace char.

Answer (score 0):

As I expect you are finding the Redshift regexp engine is not as fully configurable as you would like.  I think this has to do with when it was forked from Postgres but the 'why' doesn't matter.  In these case I find that simplifying to be the best approach to getting to success. ("Yes", this lack of regexp full functionality is a pain.  Maybe someone knows the magic to get Redshift to do all that we want.)

Here's a KISS approach:

```
select regexp_substr(txt, '^[^-]*') || regexp_replace(regexp_substr(txt, ' - ([^-]*) - '), '[^\\s-]', 'X') || regexp_replace(txt, '^[^-]* - [^-]* - (.*)$', '$1')
from (

select '002 - KLAMPFER - Sy 52-' as txt
union select '002 - DFTF GTFL - Ty 52-5-5+L'
union select '002 - AMPFER TT OT - Vy 5-5+L'
union select '002 - AMP 3>?> - Ty 52-5-5'
);
```

Now if your are certain that the delimiter next ' - ' will not show up 3 times in the text (the above code doesn't assume this) then this is simpler (using split_part()):

```
select split_part(txt, ' - ', 1) || ' - ' ||  
    regexp_replace(split_part(txt, ' - ', 2), '[^\\s]', 'X') || ' - ' ||
    split_part(txt, ' - ', 3) 
from (

select '002 - KLAMPFER - Sy 52-' as txt
union select '002 - DFTF GTFL - Ty 52-5-5+L'
union select '002 - AMPFER TT OT - Vy 5-5+L'
union select '002 - AMP 3>?> - Ty 52-5-5'
);
```